# Bound Multiple Times issue when using Hilt for UI Test, TestInstalln

Tags: android, kotlin, ui-testing, dagger-hilt, android-instrumentation

I've created a fake urlprovider binding and annotated with TestInstallIN

```
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [UrlModuleBindings::class]
)
abstract class FakeAppBindings {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsUrlProvider(urlProvider: FakeUrlProvider): UrlProvider
}
```

my Prod UrlProvider looks like

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class UrlModuleBindings {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsUrlProvider(urlProvider: DefaultUrlProvider): UrlProvider
}
```

when I'm running the UI test getting the error **UrlProvider is bound multiple times:**

As per the documentation everything seems correct, can I know what is the issue with this.

Comment: Does it matter where this is created? Are you creating this inside your test path or source path?

Also can i grab a link to the "documentation" you're reading? :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing This was created inside test path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Brad, the issue was with the AppModule, I was using Includes whereas hilt doesn't need Includes as it already has InstallIn annotation for this purpose. Once I remove it the UI test starts to work.

More details.

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3209

Comment: For me it still doesn't work and I am not even using Includes with Module annotation anywhere

Comment: Can you share the repo or sample code?